# calling image from server in android

Tags: android, json

Hello i have [this](http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?identifier=123&format=json) Json output and i am calling in my android app. I am able to get picture path but how can i display picture instead of path . here is the code

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {
      Prefs myprefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
        // install handler for processing gui update messages
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=" + 
        Test.this.myprefs.getPersonalno());

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("services");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("pic", "Picture : " + e.getString("employeepic"));
                map.put("serviceinfo", "" +  e.getString("employeename")+ " : "+ e.getString("starttime")
                        +" To " +  e.getString("endtime"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "pic", "serviceinfo" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

    }
```

This is path which i am getting in my android app

```
pictures/file83915.jpg
```

Here i am calling picture

```
map.put("pic", "Picture : " + e.getString("employeepic"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this class for downloading image from server
Hope it will help you...!! When you have got your image URLs list from your server or any source, then used it like this to download that particular Image.

```
GetImage.downloadFile("pictures/file83915.jpg", new ImageDownloaded()
{
    @Override
    public void imageDownloaded(Bitmap result){
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void imageDownloadedFailed(){
    }

});
```

Where the GetImage class is:

```
public class GetImage
{
    public static void  downloadFile(final String fileUrl, final ImageDownloaded img)
    {
        AsyncTask<String , Void, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<String , Void, Bitmap>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                Bitmap bmImg;
                URL myFileUrl =null;
                if(fileUrl.equals(""))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                try
                {
                    myFileUrl= new URL("http://yourURl/" +fileUrl.replace(" ", "%20"));
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect(); 

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    return bmImg;
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap results)
            {
                if(results != null)
                img.imageDownloaded(results);
                else
                    img.imageDownloadedFailed();
            }

        };
        task.execute("");


    }

    public static abstract class ImageDownloaded
    {
        public abstract void imageDownloaded(Bitmap result);
        public abstract void imageDownloadedFailed();
    }


}
```

I used `CustomAdapter` class to show the data in the list with Images like this.
in the method `getView()` I used this thread like this.

```
public View getView(params....)
{
    View row ;//Inflataion blah blah
    Bitmap thumb = myCustomObject.getBitmap();
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

    if(thumb == null)
    {
        GetImage.downloadFile(myCustomObject.getImagePath(), new ImageDownloaded()
        {

            @Override
            public void imageDownloaded(Bitmap result){
                myCustomObject.setBmp(result);
                image.setImageBitmap(myCustomObject.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void imageDownloadedFailed(){
            }

        });         
    }
    else
    image.setImageBitmap(thumb);
}
```

`MyCustomObject` is my `class` that encapsulates the data from server as well as Image from server and `implements Parcelable interface`. First I get data through `JSON` and then get Image in `Adapter`. It can also be passed to the any `DetailActivity`

Comment: @Adil Soomro thanks for your concern . if i implement this code , do i will be able to put the code in json map which is stated in the code ?

Comment: @Adil Soomro as it will be dynamic and a lot of images

Comment: @umar: you will need a custom object to encapsulate the `String` and `Bitmap` inside a single variable.

Comment: @Adil Soomro please can u clarify what you mean or any example , i am quite new to android and i have to implement this

Comment: You will made a class `Earthquake`, which will include fields of all the variables returning as JSON object, `String startTime, endTime, service, employe;` etc.

Comment: I have added another function (edited the question )can i put the functionality to it , the one you are asking about