# populating a listView with images on the device

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-sdcard

Ok so Ive spent the last two days looking for a good simple example of how to use the images on a device to populate a list view and Ive come to the conclusion that there is no easy way to do this. I know that everytime I put together bits and pieces from some one elses examples that I usually end up with lots of extra code i dont need. Can some one please show me how to simply load images from the device to a list view. There is no book, tutorial, or post on here that just simply shows how to do this and its kind of funny and crazy at the same time.

Comment: so far the only part I could find online that makes sense is the image collection portion of the code i need however I cant figure out how to implement it   http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-asynchronously-load-image-from-sd-card/#section-comments

Comment: so, you just wanted to show images in listview stored on the device. Is it so please confirm.

Comment: You could refer to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536091/calling-image-from-server-in-android/6536408#6536408)

Comment: Hi Anup :) Yes I want to pull the images from the device to view them in a listView. Once I get that far Im sure I can get the onclick and everything else set up that I want to use it for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the rest of the code, using the SDImageLoader linked to above from here: http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-asynchronously-load-image-from-sd-card

The ListAdapter class:

```
public class PBListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

//MEMBERS:

private int mLayoutId;
private SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter mDbHelper;
private final SDImageLoader mImageLoader = new SDImageLoader();


//METHODS:

public PBListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
    super(context, layout, c, new String[] {}, new int[] {});
    mLayoutId = layout; 
    mDbHelper = new SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter(context);
    mDbHelper.open();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(mLayoutId, parent, false);
    return v;               
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {   

    String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_TITLE));
    String species = mDbHelper.fetchSpeciesName(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_SPECIES)));
    int pounds = c.getInt((c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_POUNDS)));
    int ounces = c.getInt((c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_OUNCES)));
    int drams = c.getInt((c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_DRAMS)));  
    String weight = pounds + context.getString(R.string.addcapture_pounds) + " " +
                    ounces + context.getString(R.string.addcapture_ounces) + " " + 
                    drams + context.getString(R.string.addcapture_drams);
    String photoFilePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_PHOTO));
    String comment = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter.KEY_CAPTURES_COMMENT));

    TextView nameView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pb_row_species_name);
    TextView weightView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pb_row_capture_weight);
    TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pb_row_capture_title);
    TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pb_row_capture_comment);
    ImageView photoView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.pb_row_capture_photo);

    mImageLoader.load(context, photoFilePath, photoView);       
    nameView.setText(species);
    titleView.setText(title);
    weightView.setText(weight);
    commentView.setText(comment);
}
}
```

In the actual ListActivity, in your onCreate() set the list adapter:

```
private void bindData() {       
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllPBs();
    startManagingCursor(c);     
    setListAdapter(new PBListAdapter(this, R.layout.pb_list_item, c));
}
```

In my example the absolute filepaths for the images are stored in the database when added via the app.

Comment: Garcon you are the man :) Im gonna try this out and see if it works

Comment: Hey Garcon.....Ive tried to use your example to just get the images from my sd card but Im having trouble figuring out what exactly to use in place of your SpecimenHunterDatabaseAdapter mDbHelper. I dont think I need a database to use the images from the sd card in a list view.....do I?

Comment: You can get rid of that part. That's only there so I can use fetchSpeciesName() - in which case there are probably more efficient ways to do it but I'm pretty new to SQL with this project and it's not like it makes the app slow :)